# How to change other objects based on a html select element

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html, razor

I am implementing the graphical interface to manage a roles on a site. I am using ASP.NET MVC with Razor to display the view

Here is my current screen:

[image]

Here is my code for the combo box:

```
   <p>
    <label>Select User</label>
    <span class="field">
        <select name="userSelect">
            <option value="">Choose One</option>
            @foreach (var item in Model.Users)
            {
                <option value="@item.Id">@item.UserName</option>
            }
        </select>
    </span>
</p>
```

Now obviously when the person selects the user I want the appropriate roles to be loaded into the dual select below.

From what I have read I will need to use jQuery for this, however I have not done any jQuery before so some nice examples would be great.

Here is my code for the dual select, however it has not got any dynamic code to populate it with the correct fields yet as obviously this posts answer will affect how its done.

```
<p>
    <label>Select Roles</label>
    <span id="dualselect" class="dualselect">
        <select name="RolesSelect" multiple="multiple" size="10">
            <option value="">Admin</option>
            <option value="">User</option>
            <option value="">Technical</option>
            <option value="">Sales</option>
            <option value="">End User</option>
            <option value="">Cient<option>
        </select>
        <span class="ds_arrow">
            <span class="arrow ds_prev">&laquo;</span>
            <span class="arrow ds_next">&raquo;</span>
        </span>
        <select name="select4" multiple="multiple" size="10">
            <option value=""></option>
        </select>
    </span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't *need* to use JQuery, but it's probably the quickest/easiest approach to take for a beginner.

http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/getting-started/

Comment: quickest / easiest (SOUNDS GOOD TO ME). O k besides just the reference to Jquery. What is the process or method which I should take? On the combobox click event I obviously then need to get the user and locate his roles and then inject the values into the html?